# Removing switch statments

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
private P2SAFile populateP2SAFile(File file, Message out) throws Exception {
    String filename = file.getName();
    FileType fileType = extractFileTypeFromFileName(filename);
    String instrument = null;
    Boolean calibrated = null;
    String destination = null;
    Date date = new Date();

    switch (fileType) {
    case ANCILLARY:
        instrument = Constants.Instrument.LYRA.name();
        calibrated = Boolean.FALSE;
        destination = getDestination(fileType, instrument);
        break;

    case DAILY_DIFF_MOVIE:
    case DAILY_MOVIE:
        instrument = Constants.Instrument.SWAP.name();
        calibrated = Boolean.TRUE;
        date = extractDateFromFileName(filename);
        destination =
            getYearMonthDestination(date,
                                    Constants.Instrument.SWAP.name().toLowerCase(),
                                    Constants.DataType.MOVIE.name().toLowerCase());
        break;

    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown file type " + filename);
    }

    out.setHeader(Constants.FILE_DESTINATION_HEADER, destination);
    FileExtension fileExtension = FileExtension.valueOf(getFileExtension(filename).toUpperCase());

    P2SAFile p2saFile = getP2SAFile(filename, fileExtension.name(), instrument, calibrated);
    p2saFile.setFilePath(destination);
    p2saFile.setExtension(fileExtension.name());
    p2saFile.setFileDate(date);
    p2saFile.setFileSize(file.length());
    p2saFile.setFileType(fileType.name());
    p2saFile.setProcessingLevel(Constants.NOT_APPLICABLE);
    return p2saFile;
}
```

I would like to refactor out the switch statements as new types will be added in future and it is a bit ugly. I know one solution to this is to create classes to do this using strategy or command pattern or maybe I could create a factory which returned the right type.

Any comments welcome
Thanks

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: Please give us more context, so that we can give you better advice. What does this code accomplish? What are the `FileType` and `P2SAFile` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FileType appears to me good to encapsulate itself all the things you need.

I used many strategies to archieve same result to illustrate how to use enum as you like. I think it works with very few changes

```
public enum FileType{

ANCILLARY(Constants.Instrument.LYRA.name(), Boolean.FALSE){
    @Override
    public String getDestination(){
        return AClass.staticMethod.extractDestination(this.name(),this.instrument);
    }
},
DAILY_DIFF_MOVIE(Constants.Instrument.SWAP.name(), Boolean.TRUE){
    @Override
    public Date getDate(String fileName){
        return AClass.staticMethod.extractDateFromFileName(filename);
    }
    @Override
    public String getDestination(){
        return AClass.staticMethod.extractDestinationYearMonth(getDate(),this.instrument.toLowerCase(), Constants.DataType.MOVIE.name().toLowerCase()));
    }
},
DAILY_MOVIE(Constants.Instrument.SWAP.name(),Boolean.TRUE){
    @Override
    public Date getDate(String fileName){
        return getDateFromFile(filename);
    }
    @Override
    public String getDestination(){
        return AClass.staticMethod.extractDestinationYearMonth(getDate(),Constants.Instrument.SWAP.name().toLowerCase(), Constants.DataType.MOVIE.name().toLowerCase()));
    }
}
;


private final String instrument;
private final Boolean calibrated;

private FileType(String instrument, Boolean calibrated){
    this.instrument = instrument;
    this.calibrated = calibrated;
}

public String getInstrument(){
    return this.instrument;
}

public Boolean isCalibrated(){
    return this.calibrated;
}

abrstract public String getDestination(AnInstanceWIthStrategy object);

public Date getDate(String fileName){
    return new Date();
}

private Date getDateFromFile(String fileName){
    return filename.substring(foo);
}
```

and then your method will looks like:

```
private P2SAFile populateP2SAFile(File file, Message out) throws Exception {
    String filename = file.getName();

    FileType fileType = null;
    try{
        FileType fileType = extractFileTypeFromFileName(filename);
    }
    catch{
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown file type " + filename);
    }

    out.setHeader(Constants.FILE_DESTINATION_HEADER, fileType.getDestination());
    FileExtension fileExtension = FileExtension.valueOf(getFileExtension(filename).toUpperCase());

    P2SAFile p2saFile = getP2SAFile(filename, fileExtension.name(), fileType.getInstrument(), fileType.isCalibrated());
    p2saFile.setFilePath(fileType.getDestination());
    p2saFile.setExtension(fileExtension.name());
    p2saFile.setFileDate(fileType.getDate(filename));
    p2saFile.setFileSize(file.length());
    p2saFile.setFileType(fileType.name());
    p2saFile.setProcessingLevel(Constants.NOT_APPLICABLE);
    return p2saFile;
}
```